# Django PasswordChangeForm not displaying message

Tags: django

I am using the Django PasswordChangeForm

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('change_password')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    url = 'registration/change_password.html'
    return render(request, url, {'form': form})
```

But on success the *messages.success* does not appear

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display messages in your template you should add it in your template

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: But I'm using PasswordChangeForm and don't have a template (or do I?)

Comment: put it in your change_password.html

Comment: Perfect. Easy once you spell it out